# ERROR in ./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css 3:0 > You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-leaflet

I am working on a project with react-leaflet and run into the problem where while building I get this error:

```
    ERROR in ./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css 3:0
    Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:0)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
    | /* required styles */
    | 
    > .leaflet-pane,
    | .leaflet-tile,
    | .leaflet-marker-icon,
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

As this error started after importing the leaflet.css into my project like this:

```
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
```

All my imports in this file are:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { LatLngExpression } from "leaflet";
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup, ZoomControl, ScaleControl, Viewport } from 'react-leaflet';
import { Classes } from "jss";

import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
```

To solve this I added css-loader, file-loader and style-loader to my project (using yarn).
After that I changed my webpack config to this:

```
module: {
  rules: [{
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
    use: [{
      loader: 'file-loader'
    }]
  }, {
    test: /\.css$/i,
    use: [{
      loader: 'style-loader'
    },{ 
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        url: false, 
        modules: false
      }
    }]
  }]
}
```

However I still get the same error while building.
I tried several solutions, trying to add url-loader for instance.

Somehow it does not make any difference, I keep getting the same error.

Here is my complete Webpack config. Please understand I am using EJS and node here as well.

```
import * as path from 'path';
import * as HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import * as ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin from 'fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin';

import { Mode } from './enum/Mode';
import { Languages } from './enum/Languages';

// only when condition is met
const when = (condition:any, returnValue:any) => (condition ? returnValue : undefined);

// remove empty values from object
const removeEmpty = (obj) => {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((newObj, key) => {
        if (obj[key] !== undefined && obj[key] !== null) {
            newObj[key] = obj[key];
        }
        return newObj;
    }, {});
};

module.exports = async (env, argv) => {

    // get arguments
    const { mode = Mode.PRODUCTION } = argv;

    // array holding the webpack configs
    const webpackConfigs = [];

    // get languages from cli arguments
    const languages = argv.languages
        ? argv.languages.split(',')
        : 'NL';

    // build config for every target in every language
    languages.forEach((language) => {

        // build the actual config
        webpackConfigs.push({
            mode,
            devtool: 'inline-source-map', // Needed for chrome dev tools

            entry: {
                app: [
                    'console-polyfill',
                    path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src/index.tsx')
                ]
            },

            output: removeEmpty({
                publicPath: '/',
                path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), `build/${Languages[language]}/`),
                filename: mode === Mode.DEVELOPMENT ? '[name].js' : '[name]-[contenthash].min.js'
            }),

            resolve: {
                extensions: [
                    '.js',
                    '.jsx',
                    '.ts',
                    '.tsx'
                ],
                moduleExtensions: []
            },

            plugins: [
                new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                    mobile: true,
                    inject: false,
                    title: mode === Mode.PRODUCTION ? 'production' : 'Development',
                    template: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'webpack/index.ejs'),
                    templateOptions: {
                        language: Languages[language]
                    }
                }),

                when(mode === Mode.DEVELOPMENT, // DEVELOPMENT only
                    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin()
                )
            ],

            devServer: removeEmpty({
                disableHostCheck: true, // Security issue
                hot: true,
                hotOnly: false,
                compress: true,
                watchContentBase: true,
                host: 'localhost',
                contentBase: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'webpack/public'),
                port: 8080,
                stats: 'minimal',
                watchOptions: {
                    ignored: /node_modules/
                }

            }),

            module: {
                exprContextCritical: false,
                rules: [
                    { // babel javascript/typescript (no type checking), also see ./babel.config.js
                        test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
                        exclude: /node_modules/,
                        use: {
                            loader: 'babel-loader',
                            options: {
                                presets: [
                                    ['@babel/preset-env', {
                                        targets: {
                                            browsers: [
                                                'firefox >= 40',
                                                'chrome >= 49',
                                                'edge >= 12',
                                                'opera >= 47',
                                                'safari >= 9',
                                                'android >= 5',
                                                'ios >= 10'
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }]
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    { // images
                        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                        use: [{
                            loader: 'file-loader'
                        }]
                    },

                    {
                        test: /\.css$/i,
                        exclude: /node_modules/,
                        use: [{
                            loader: 'style-loader'
                        }, {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                url: false, // leaflet uses relative paths
                                modules: false
                            }
                        }],
                    },

                    { // sourcemaps
                        loader: 'source-map-loader',
                        exclude: /node_modules/
                    },

                    { // html template
                        test: /\.ejs$/u,
                        loader: 'ejs-loader'
                    }

                ]

            }

        });

    });

    return webpackConfigs;
};
```

To be complete I am using:

```
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-leaflet": "2.7.0",
    "leaflet": "1.6.0",
    "@babel/core": "7.9.6",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "css-loader": "3.5.3",
    "file-loader": "6.0.0",
    "style-loader": "1.2.1",
    "webpack": "4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.10.3"
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to load CSS file as a JS module.

This line is the problem: `import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';`

Try this instead: `import leaflet from 'leaflet'`

Comment: Thank for the help I tried, but then css is failing. 

I rather import the css then having to add a ```<link rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" />``` to my html file.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: my fault, sorry. In react is it fine to load CSS this way.

Can you please share your webpack configuration?

Comment: I can do the total, but understand I am using EJS ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar and guessed at the solution.  I guess the location it cares about for leaflet is node_modules but I am new at this and can't tell you more than that, only that adding what appears to be a reference to the directory in the webpack.config.js solved the problem.  My error message did not include the exact directory with the problem so thank you for this question

In my case the solution looked like this.  I added something to the end of the include line to the css rule in the module section of the webpack file.  The include line is what you may be needing. Specifically the correct location to the the node_module which is what I added to the end of the include line

```
   {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: [APP_DIR, /superset-ui.+\/src/,/superset-ui.+\/node_modules/],
        use: [
          isDevMode ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: isDevMode,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```